# CircuiTikZ - change position of voltage label along open draw

Tags: positioning, circuitikz

Is there a way to adjust the appearance of an voltage label between two points? For default the label `$U_1$` will be placed midway of the voltage arrow, but I want it to appear at a point realtive to the length of the voltage arrow, for example at quarter way or at 70% way.

```
\usepackage[americaninductors, straightvoltages]{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{circuitikz}
        \draw (0,0) to [open, v^=$U_1$] (2,0);
    \end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends basically on how new is your `circuitikz`. Since 1.2.1 you can use the coordinates for voltages and do something like that:

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[EFvoltages, americaninductors, straightvoltages]{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{circuitikz}
        \draw 
        (0,0) to [open, v, name=O1] (2,0);
        \draw [thin, -Triangle] (O1-Vfrom) -- (O1-Vto) node[above, pos=0.2]{$U_1$};
    \end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image: Example image]

Notice that I added the voltage direction option (please look at the warnings!). I copy here [the relevant part of the manual](https://osl.ugr.es/CTAN/graphics/pgf/contrib/circuitikz/doc/circuitikzmanual.pdf#ae)...

[image: Excerpt of 1.2.3 manual of circuitikz]

Answer (score 3):

I hope to have understand well. You can shift the label manually using with the command `\mkern<value>`...just this is like an example.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[americaninductors, straightvoltages]{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{circuitikz}
        \draw (0,0) to [open, v^=$U_1$] (2,0);
        \draw (0,0) to [open, v^=$\mkern30mu U_2$] (2,0);
    \end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks, but I'm rather searching for an option to define a position relative to the length of the arrow. Like at the beginning or at quarter way.

Comment: @DraUX Hence your question is relative to the lenght of an arrow (voltage)? If you prefer I delete my answer or later I will read the recent manual of `circuitikz`.

Comment: I tried to specify my question. I hope it makes clear, for what I'm searching.

Answer (score 1):

one solution is an extra node at the right position and replace the voltage label with a protected space like this

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[americaninductors, straightvoltages]{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{circuitikz}
        \draw 
        (0,0) to [open, v=\ ] (2,0)
        (0.5,0) node[above]{$U_1$};
    \end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]

but its not a very smart solution...