# European Voltage has different shifts for an open path and a component path. How to return to backward compatibility?

Tags: circuitikz

I've noticed that recent changes of Circuitikz modified the behaviour of european voltage arrows. When an open path is used instead of a componente path the voltage arrow tip is placed in different positions. The open path compatibility is important to allow the placement of a voltage arrow after drawing the component path. Is there a simple fix for this?

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[usenames]{color} %used for font color
\usepackage{amssymb} %maths
\usepackage{amsmath} %maths
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %useful to type directly diacritic characters
\usepackage[siunitx,american, RPvoltages]{circuitikz}  

% Definitions to help locate nodes. Comment out the second definition when done!
\def\coord(#1){coordinate(#1)}
%\def\coord(#1){node[circle, inner sep=1pt,pin={[teal, overlay, inner sep=0.5pt, font=\tiny, pin distance=0.3cm, pin edge={teal, line width=0.5pt, shorten <=-2pt, {Kite[length=1.5mm]}-{Circle[open,line width=0.5pt,length=0.75mm]}}]45:#1}](#1){}} 

\newcommand{\flagv}[5] %{x,y}{dx,dy}{name}{label}{color}  e.g. \flagv{0,0}{-0.2,0.5}{A}{$A_L$}{red}
{\draw[#5!50!gray,Kite-] (#1) -- ($(#1)+(#2)$) node[circle, very thin, inner sep=0pt, minimum size=8pt, draw=#5!25!white, fill=#5!10,font=\scriptsize](#3){#4};
}

\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
    \draw[european voltages](-1,0) to[short,-*]  (0,0) \coord(1) to[R, v=$V_{12}$] ++(3,0)\coord(2) to[short,*-] ++(1,0);

    \draw[european, blue, color=blue!50!gray] (1) to[open, v^=$V_{12}$] (2);
    \draw[european voltages, color=red!50!gray] (1) to[open, v^=$V_{12}$, voltage shift=2.0 ] (2);

    \flagv{1}{0,-0.75}{A}{$A$}{red}
    \flagv{2}{0,-0.75}{B}{$B$}{red}

  \draw[european, blue, color=blue!50!gray] (A) to[open, v=$V_{AB}$] (B);

\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi! I am not  sure what you want to achieve --- yes, the position has changed because before the arrows in some components were too near to them. You can revert using one of the roll-off (see manual at section 1.9), but I think this is a XY-problem. Have you seen the new access to anchors, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/560331/38080?

Comment: Hi Rmano, I do appreciate the new flexibility with the anchors. I only noticed that the arrows were touching the wires when using to[open,v=$v_{12}$}. But your tip solved the problem. By the way, all Circuitikz updates has been great and well thought, but I admit, the changes sometimes requires a lot of reworking. Being able to have a simple keyword to locally solve big changes is always helpful.

Comment: Thanks for thr nice words. You're right, and I try to create local key to go back to legacy mode every time something changes, but there are changes (like the big voltage and path-to rewrite) where that's impossible... That is the reason I created the roll-back points, although I understand is suboptimal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what are you trying to achieve here, but the "open voltage" behaviour can be changed with the (misnamed, I will adjust it*) `american open voltage` key (see section 4.5.5).

```latex
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}   % default since TeXLive 2018
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % default since TeXLive 2018
\usepackage[siunitx,american, RPvoltages]{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
    \draw[blue, color=red!50!gray] (0,0)
        node[draw, circle, inner sep=1pt]{}
        to[european voltages, open, v=$V_{AB}$]
        (3,0)
        node[draw, circle, inner sep=1pt]{}
        ;
    \ctikzset{american open voltage=legacy}
    \draw[blue, color=blue!50!gray] (0,0)
        node[draw, circle, inner sep=1pt]{}
        to[european voltages, open, v=$V_{AB}$]
        (3,0)
        node[draw, circle, inner sep=1pt]{}
        ;
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of the previous snippet]

- it will [change to `open voltage position` from `1.2.4` onward](https://github.com/circuitikz/circuitikz/pull/437), maintaining backward compatibility of course...